# d3 typescript bindings: cannot read property 'ticks' of undefined

Tags: d3.js, typescript-typings

I'm having trouble figuring out the Typescript bindings for parts of d3.  What I'm trying now:

```
private xScale: ScaleTime<number, number>;
private xAxis: Axis<Date | number | { valueOf(): number }>;
...
this.xScale = scaleTime()
    .domain([new Date('2017-01-01'), new Date('2017-12-31')])
    .range([0, 100]);
this.xAxis = axisBottom(this.xScale);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(50,50)")
  .call(this.xAxis);
```

This gives me `ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ticks' of undefined`.

I shouldn't have to specify a tick configuration - the default is good enough to prove that it works - but doing so (either using `ticks()` or `tickArguments()`) didn't help.

The function `axisBottom()` is typed like this:

```
function axisBottom<Domain>(scale: AxisScale<Domain>): Axis<Domain>;
```

but I'm passing it a `ScaleTime`.  I think that's what I must do, because that's what `scaleTime()` returns.  `ScaleTime` objects do have a `ticks()` method (at least, one is specified in the interface).

I'm not sure how to connect all these objects.  I'm persisting because I think it's worthwhile - d3 can be tricky to use, and maintaining type safety makes things much easier..

Versions of everything:

- @types/d3: "^4.11.1",
- @types/d3-selection-multi: "^1.0.6",
- d3: "^4.11.0",
- d3-selection-multi: "^1.0.1",

Answer (score 1):

Sorry.  I actually had the typescript bindings right.  My problem was an error in the way I was using the Angular component lifecycle, which made it that the scale wasn't property initialized.  Sorry for the noise...

Comment: Thanks this helped me find my bug also, by pointing me to the scale object.